# Copy a single column from an excel file to a text file

Tags: vba

I am using the attached [Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9abgf.png) and at the moment the code that I have copies all the columns to the txt file.

I have 2 columns and the column "B" needs to be copied to txt file.

Comment: add code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Code You Use

```
 For P=1 to Lastcolumn
 wsData=ActiveSheet.Cells(1,P).value
 Next
```

I Think This Is your Problem. You Split All the cell Values and then Write it into the txt file . You just wonna try to mention that Particular row count and you will get Solution.